# How to set button background image to wrap content in a table layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

Im implementing tablelayout dynamically code below.

```
private void showCowsTblField() {
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRowsInField - 1; row++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumnsInField - 1; column++) {
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (column == 0) {
                textSno[row][column].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                tableRow.addView(textSno[row][column]);
            } else {
                blocks[row][column].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layoutParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
                tableRow.addView(blocks[row][column]);
            }
            tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bar_1);
        }
        tblCows.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

here block is a class extends Button class,
in this class iam setting background image as

```
this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_button);
```

Here problem is the button background image size(height) is changing to fit to tablerow height. which is not looking good.

How i can set button background image to actual size (wrapcontent) in table row.

Please let me know....
Thanks.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code in my class; which extends button class

```
this.setMaxHeight(26);
this.setMaxWidth(54);
```

solved issue.:)

Answer (score 1):

See if that helps - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

You can set it only if you use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Your code must look something like this:

```
class MyButton extends ImageButton{...}


this.setScaleType(scaleType);
```

Comment: I tried another way this.setMaxHeight(26);  this.setMaxWidth(54); solved issue... anyway thanks.....

Comment: I don't think that setting hardcoded dimensions is good practice.

Comment: hmm... yeah you are right... for now i jst want move on to nxt task... instead of spending some more time for this logic....